# React onClick function call refreshes app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a simple note taking app in the style of google keepnote. When I press the the add button from the create are component it calls the function in the app component that will add the note to an array for rendering.  The function call works just fine but then the whole app refreshes and any data is lost.

I cant work out what is causing the refresh.

the App component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Note from "./Note";
import CreateArea from "./CreateArea";

function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState({ id: "", title: "", content: "" });

  function addNote(note) {
    console.log(note);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <CreateArea newNote={addNote} />
      <Note key={1} title="Note title" content="Note content" />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The CreateArea component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function CreateArea(props) {
  const [note, setNote] = useState({ title: "", content: "" });

  function handleChange(event) {
    if (event === null || event === undefined) return;

    const { name, value } = event.target;

    if (name === "title") {
      setNote(prevValue => {
        return {
          title: value,
          content: prevValue.content
        };
      });
    } else {
      setNote(prevValue => {
        return {
          title: prevValue.title,
          content: value
        };
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input onChange={handleChange} name="title" placeholder="Title" />
        <textarea
          onChange={handleChange}
          name="content"
          placeholder="Take a note..."
          rows="3"
        />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            props.newNote(note);
          }}
        >
          Add
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CreateArea;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are clicking a button in a form.  The form is trying to submit, which refreshes the page.  You can add `e.preventDefault` to stop that.

```js
        <button
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            props.newNote(note);
          }}
        >
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default behavior of form submission.

In your `OnClick` event pass the event as an argument:

```
<button
      onClick={(e) => {
        props.newNote(e,note);
      }}
    >
      Add
    </button>
```

and while calling this function on parent component:

```
function addNote(e,note) {
    e.preventDefault()  // prevent the default behavior
    console.log(note);
  }
```